# Unable to load URL when drupal is installed on a server

Tags: uri

My drupal URL was loading normally until when I deleted two modules in the Windows server.Now after deleting the modules from the server the site is not loading.
I know that deleting a module does not result in the URL not loading it simply removes the module from the Module List.

I can't exactly find out what exactly is the reason behind this

[Update]I have checked under my Modules Menu and verified that both the modules are disabled and then un-installed from the modules list.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that deleting a module does not result in the URL not loading it simply removes the module from the Module List.

That's incorrect. If you delete a module without first disabling and uninstalling it, you could easily break the whole site. You're removing code that you've told the system exists when you installed the module, and it has no way to recover from that.

You should restore the deleted files temporarily, disable then uninstall the module properly with Drush, or through the UI, and only then should you delete the files.

Comment: Plz check the update.

Comment: The registry for your site may still be broken. Follow @Clive's advice.